# Malware present in my Ubuntu, says some tabs in Chrome

Tags: 14.04, malware

[image: Security Threat]
I have been getting some new tabs like the two titled "WARNING - SECURITY..." with voiceover saying something to the effect: "You probably have installed some software that puts your computer's security in threat"

I need help to, firstly, determine whether these threats are true. If yes, how to get rid of these tabs appearing, and if no, then how to getrid of the threat.

Any help is appreciated.

I am running 14.04 Ubuntu 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 5):

It's spam+scareware.  Just dismiss it, and reconsider your choices on which websites you frequent if it scares you.

If at first glance, you didn't know better than to believe it - you shouldn't be doing whatever it was that you were doing that used such a promiscuous ad network.